# ¿Cual es el MIME Content-type para los archivos PHP?

Tags: php, mime

Estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo PHP y necesito saber cómo es su `MIME Content-type` para poder ejecutarlo correctamente en un navegador.

¿Cúal es el `MIME Content-type` que se debe utilizar para archivos `.php`?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta parece bastante pobre, igualmente te dejo la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Adrián te recomiendo mejores tus respuestas para que no sean cerradas por la comunidad o tengan calificación negativa, desarrolla más tu pregunta, agrega lo que has investigado, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `MIME Content-type` para archivos `PHP` puede ser uno de los siguiente dependiendo el contexto:

```
text/plain
text/x-php
application/x-php
application/x-httpd-php
application/x-httpd-php-source
```

> No hay ningún tipo MIME oficial registrado en IANA para PHP. [Lista IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

`PHP` provee la función [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php) para detectar el `MIME Content-type` de un archivo:

```
$filename = "./info.php";
echo mime_content_type($filename);
// resultado: text/x-php
```

Desde desde la linea de comandos de `Ubuntu` también lo podemos consultar

```
file -i nombre_archivo.php
//Resultado: nombre_archivo.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: gracias, era lo que buscaba

Comment: Hay **[una función](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)** que detecta el MIME Content Type.

Comment: OK @A.Cedano lo añado a la respuesta.